# What is the maximum number of sockets that select() can handle?

Tags: c#, sockets

I want to handle multiple clients without the use of threads, so I've read about select() but I can't find any information about how many sockets it can handle, I think that its default is 64 and in order to increase that limit I have to do some tweaking, is that correct? and what is the tweaking that I must do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>I would guess that the number is in fact the Winsock default of 64.</del> You could easily verify this simply by writing some code that calls `Socket.Select()` with an increasing number of `Socket` instances until it fails (*).

I would be surprised if you can effectively change the limit in managed code, since the limit is determined at compile time by overriding a #define in the unmanaged code being compiled. Since you don't have the option of recompiling the `Socket` class, this suggests you won't be able to change the limit.

Note that all of this is moot anyway. If you are writing managed code, there's really no reason to use `Socket.Select()`, and every reason to use one of the several good asynchronous APIs provided with the `Socket` class. One of the easiest is to wrap the `Socket` instance in a `NetworkStream` and perform your I/O using the `ReadAsync()` and `WriteAsync()` methods.

For that matter, even in Winsock there's little reason to use the `select()` function, since the Winsock support for IOCP (overlapped I/O) is so much more efficient, and free of any specific limits like that.

(*) **EDIT:** so, I actually tested this and it failed at a surprisingly high count of 16373 sockets. So based on that quick and dirty test, you can successfully do 16372 sockets. Still, I wouldn't do that.

Comment: "the limit is determined at compile time" - do you know where you got that piece of information? I'd like to read some more about that.

Comment: Sure. Check the [`select()` function documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx). Look for "The variable FD_SETSIZE determines the maximum number of descriptors in a set. (The default value of FD_SETSIZE is 64, which can be modified by defining FD_SETSIZE to another value before including Winsock2.h.)" Note that this is a compile-time constant which the include headers depend on.